# How can I improve the following lambda function for finding the first 4 elements in a vector

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

For practice, I am trying to copy the first 4 entries different than 2 from a vector of integers using copy_if.

This seems to work but if there is a better way of writing this lambda then I'd like to learn the proper way. Cheers.

```
   vector<int> first_vector = {2,8,50,2,4,5,9,12};
   vector<int> second_vector (first_vector.size());
   int count_elem=0;
   auto it = copy_if(first_vector.begin(),first_vector.end(),second_vector.begin(),
            [&count_elem]
            (int i){
                  if(i!=2 && count_elem!=4)
                  {
                      count_elem++;
                      return 1;
                  }
                  return 0;});
```

Comment: Your question is not particularly clear. Do you mean a better way to solve the problem, a better way to format the lambda, better code inside the lambda? What do you mean by better? More concise, more idiomatic, clearer code, are there any obvious errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not copying all of the values from `first_vector` to `second_vector`, you should not initialize `second_vector` to hold the same number of elements as `first_vector`.  You are creating more elements than you want, where the extra elements are value-initialized to `0`.

I would suggest `reserve()`'ing the size of `second_vector` instead and then use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) as the destination iterator to copy to.  That way, `second_vector` ends up with only the values you want pushed and nothing else.

That would also eliminate the need for the `count_elem` variable.  You can use `second_vector.size()` to know how many values have been pushed into the vector.

```cpp
std::vector<int> first_vector = {2, 8, 50, 2, 4, 5, 9, 12};
std::vector<int> second_vector;
second_vector.reserve(4);
std::copy_if(
    first_vector.begin(), first_vector.end(),
    std::back_inserter(second_vector),
    [&](int i){
        return ((i != 2) && (second_vector.size() < 4));
    }
);
```

Do note, however, that this use of `std::copy_if()` will iterate through the entire `first_vector`, it will not stop iterating once 4 values have been pushed to `second_vector`.  It would be more efficient to simply run your own loop instead so you can break it as soon as possible:

```cpp
std::vector<int> first_vector = {2, 8, 50, 2, 4, 5, 9, 12};
std::vector<int> second_vector;
second_vector.reserve(4);
for(int i : first_vector) {
    if (i != 2) {
        second_vector.push_back(i);
        if (second_vector.size() == 4)
            break;
    }
}
```